# Global styles are not being applied to Angular library by adding "assets" to ng-package.json with ng-packagr

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am working on an angular library (version 9.1.11) with storybook, where I want to add styles globally. I know that for `ng-packagr` versions 9.x and above it is possible to copy assets into your library package as part of the build process to add styles globally.

`"ng-packagr:" "~9.1.5"` was already in devDependencies in my package.json, so I didn't reinstall it.

What I did is the following:
I created the `global.scss` file in the root of my library.
I added "assets" to my `ng-package.json` targeting my `global.scss` file.
I added styles to my `global.scss` file.
I ran an npm run build to copy the `global.scss` file into my dist folder.

After that the styles from my `global.scss` file are not being applied to my library.

What am I missing and why are the styles not being applied globally?
And how can I add styles globally to my library correctly using `ng-packagr`?

This is what the files in my library look like:

[image]

Here's what my `ng-package.json` looks like:

```
    {
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/angular-components",
  "assets": ["./global.scss"], <- ADDED HERE
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "color": "color",
      "uuid": "uuid"
    }
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "color",
    "tslib",
    "uuid"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem will be solved in 6.4 by this [PR](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/15744)

Currently there is a workaround.

Create an application to let storybook to load in angular.json

tsconfig.json need to point to the correct one.

```json
"storybook": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "styles": [
            // Add your global stylesheets
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/15855#issuecomment-908874533)

I used it with my NX project and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in ng-package.json:

```
"lib": {
      "cssUrl": "inline"
    }
```

and include global.scss from your component style.
However I suggest you to create a new library with your style and import this.